# installing and running gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed gazebo by downloading the gazebo 1.0.1 release. I followed the tutorials on http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials. Everything works fine until i use the command to roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch to launch it. I even get a message that all rosdeps installed successfully but still its not launching. The error i get is "Error [Transport.cc:102] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
Error [Node.cc:68] No namespace found
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  2589 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so".
Kindly help plz...........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41819/installing-and-running-gazebo/) by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Vishnu You SHOULD NOT install gazebo like that - it is strictly NOT recommended. If you plan to use gazebo with ROS, then install ROS and then follow the gazebo tutorials. What you have achieved is a standalone installation of gazebo - for all I know, it will NOT work with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1